# Integrating this indefinite integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\dfrac{t-2}{t+2-3\sqrt{2t-4}}dt$$
I'm not sure whether to use substitution or what.

Comment: Hint: Let $u = \sqrt{2t-4}$.

Comment: What happens when you let $u^2 = t - 2$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

With the change of variable $x=\sqrt{2t-4}$ the integral becomes
$$\int\frac{x^3}{x^2-6x+8}dx$$
then use the partial fraction decomposition (notice that $x^2-6x+8=(x-2)(x-4)$).

Comment: Great hint, Sami!

Comment: why it is becomes x^3?

Comment: @Sami thanks btw :)

Comment: is the answer is -2ln|sqrt(2t-4)-2|+ 8ln|sqrt(2t-4)-4|